# Print Multiple Barcodes on any Paper Size Line by Line

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to print multiple Bar-codes of multiple inventory items on a page Line by Line. I wrote some code which have some basic settings according to X, Y coordinates which works fine. but the problem is, the Printable Barcodes goes out of paper as you can see in below pic,

[image]

as you can see in above pic, the last one Barcode Cuts their right side and not have full in width as well as if we have 100 items then my code just print 5 Barcodes and remaining skipped. Please tell how to print all Barcodes of 100 items on a page Line by Line.

```
 pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintBarcodeEvent_PrintPage);

                System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog pdd = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
                pdd.Document = pd;

                System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = pdd.ShowDialog();

                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog pp = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog();
                    pp.Document = pd;
                    result = pp.ShowDialog();

                    //pd.Print();
                }
```

EventHandler:

```
 // The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed. 
        private void PrintBarcodeEvent_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int startX = 5;
            int startY = 5;

            Database db = new Database();
            db.DBOpen();

            for (int i = 0; i < listTobePrint.Count; i++)
            {
                String code = listTobePrint[i].Code;
                String name = db.GetByValue(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 2);
                String price = db.GetByValueForInt(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 8);

                Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Phulkari by VIRSA", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                  startX, startY, new StringFormat());

                int x2 = startX + 3;
                int y2 = startY + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Util.ImageWpfToGDI(Util.GenerateBarcode(code)), x2, y2, 100, 50);

                int x3 = startX;
                int y3 = y2 + 50;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(code, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                    x3, y3, new StringFormat());

                int x4 = startX;
                int y4 = y3 + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(name, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                   x4, y4, new StringFormat());

                int x5 = startX;
                int y5 = y4 + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Rs." + price, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                   x5, y5, new StringFormat());

                startX += 150;
                //startY += 100;
            }
            db.DBClose();
        }
```

Note: In above code, `Util.ImageWpfToGDI(Util.GenerateBarcode(code)), x2, y2, 100, 50` this piece of code will generate Barcode.

Comment: if i understand you have just one line of barcode printed, and you want to have only 5 barcode by line?

Comment: I code to do print 100 items but it just print one line with just 5 items. 6th and onward items got skipped

Comment: also so you have to adjust the number of line of barcode following the length of page?

Comment: @Frenchy thanks for your concerns i've solved by below answer

Comment: you could add a variable to adjust the number of line per page if needed, as i have done with the number of barcode per line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this solution you could adjust the number of barcode per line:

```
    private void PrintBarcodeEvent_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int startX = 5; int startY = 5;

        int NBbarcode_perLine = 5;
        int numbarcode = 0;

        Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0f); // initialize just one time before loop

        Database db = new Database(); db.DBOpen();

        for (int i = 0; i < listTobePrint.Count; i++)
        {
            String code = listTobePrint[i].Code;
            String name = db.GetByValue(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 2);
            String price = db.GetByValueForInt(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 8);

            e.Graphics.DrawString("Phulkari by VIRSA", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, startX, startY, new StringFormat());

            int x2 = startX + 3;
            int y2 = startY + 15;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Util.ImageWpfToGDI(Util.GenerateBarcode(code)), x2, y2, 100, 50);

            int x3 = startX;
            int y3 = y2 + 50;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(code, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, x3, y3, new StringFormat());

            int x4 = startX;
            int y4 = y3 + 15;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(name, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, x4, y4, new StringFormat());

            int x5 = startX;
            int y5 = y4 + 15;

            e.Graphics.DrawString("Rs." + price, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, x5, y5, new StringFormat());

            numbarcode++;
            if (numbarcode < NBbarcode_perLine)
                startX += 150;
            else
            {
                startX = 5;
                startY += 100; // space between 2 barcode in vertical (upper left). you have to adjust)
                numbarcode = 0;
            }

        }
        db.DBClose();
    }
```

Comment: please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361291/e-hasmorepages-does-not-print-2nd-page-on-printpreviewdialog