# e.HasMorePages does not print 2nd page on PrintPreviewDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to print all item's Barcode using PrintPreviewDialog. Written code works fine but the problem is on ending first page i called `e.HasMorePages = true` which creates 2nd page but not printing 2nd page. it means 2nd page got empty /blank. As you can see in below pic, at last line Barcode got cropped automatically and not print remaining Barcodes on 2nd page. Kindly help how to print remaining Barcode on 2nd page.
[image]

as you can see in above pic, the last line got cropped automatically and 2nd page not printing and got empty page.

PrintPreviewDialog code;

```
pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintBarcodeEvent_PrintPage);

                System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog pdd = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
                pdd.Document = pd;

                System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = pdd.ShowDialog();

                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog pp = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog();
                    pp.Document = pd;
                    result = pp.ShowDialog();

                    //pd.Print();
                }
```

Event:

```
 // The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed. 
        private void PrintBarcodeEvent_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int startX = 5;
            int startY = 5;

            Database db = new Database();
            db.DBOpen();

            int NBbarcode_perLine = 5;
            int numbarcode = 0;

            int barcodePerPage = 35;
            int countBarcodePerPage = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < listTobePrint.Count; i++)
            {
                String code = listTobePrint[i].Code;
                String name = db.GetByValue(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 2);
                String price = db.GetByValueForInt(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 8);

                Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Phulkari by VIRSA", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                  startX, startY, new StringFormat());

                int x2 = startX + 3;
                int y2 = startY + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Util.ImageWpfToGDI(Util.GenerateBarcode(code)), x2, y2, 100, 50);

                int x3 = startX;
                int y3 = y2 + 50;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(code, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                    x3, y3, new StringFormat());

                int x4 = startX;
                int y4 = y3 + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(name, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                   x4, y4, new StringFormat());

                int x5 = startX;
                int y5 = y4 + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Rs." + price, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                   x5, y5, new StringFormat());

                numbarcode++;
                countBarcodePerPage++;

                if (numbarcode < NBbarcode_perLine)
                    startX += 150;
                else
                {
                    startX = 5;
                    startY += 150; // space between 2 barcode in vertical (upper left). you have to adjust)
                    numbarcode = 0;
                }

                if (countBarcodePerPage >= barcodePerPage)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(countBarcodePerPage.ToString());

                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    //startX = 5;
                    //startY = 5;
                } else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
                }
            }
            db.DBClose();
            listTobePrint.Clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a global variable countbarcode (not local to PrintPage) or static and initialise To zéro.
Each time you set e.HasMorePages to true, the event PrintPage is called
 Its not a problem for a test, but i think you should put the db.open in event BeginPrint and db.close in event EndPrint . the database is open and close each time a page is printed. (maybe its not really important, but you avoid to recreate the same variable db and waste meory)

```
    private void PrintBarcodeEvent_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int startX = 5;
        int startY = 5;

        Database db = new Database();
        db.DBOpen();

        int NBbarcode_perLine = 5;
        int numbarcode = 0;

        int barcodePerPage = 35;
        int countBarcodePerPage = 0;
        int totalcodebar = listTobePrint.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < barcodePerPage; i++)
        {
            String code = listTobePrint[countbarcode].Code;
            String name = db.GetByValue(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 2);
            String price = db.GetByValueForInt(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 8);

            Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);

            e.Graphics.DrawString("Phulkari by VIRSA", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
              startX, startY, new StringFormat());

            int x2 = startX + 3;
            int y2 = startY + 15;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Util.ImageWpfToGDI(Util.GenerateBarcode(code)), x2, y2, 100, 50);

            int x3 = startX;
            int y3 = y2 + 50;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(code, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                x3, y3, new StringFormat());

            int x4 = startX;
            int y4 = y3 + 15;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(name, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
               x4, y4, new StringFormat());

            int x5 = startX;
            int y5 = y4 + 15;

            e.Graphics.DrawString("Rs." + price, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
               x5, y5, new StringFormat());

            numbarcode++;
            countbarcode++;

            if (numbarcode < NBbarcode_perLine)
                startX += 150;
            else
            {
                startX = 5;
                startY += 150; // space between 2 barcode in vertical (upper left). you have to adjust)
                numbarcode = 0;
            }

            if (countbarcode == totalcodebar) break;

            if (i == barcodePerPage - 1)
            {
                    db.DBClose();
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
            }
        }
        e.HasMorePages = false;
        db.DBClose();
        listTobePrint.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: same problem bro. on the end of page it start printing from the top of 1st page not printing 2nd page

Comment: i have to recreate a little project to debug i'll come ASAP

Comment: please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792171/unable-to-expand-first-row-height-w-r-t-2nd-row