# Unable to expand first row height w.r.t 2nd row

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to print all inventory items Barcodes at once. For print, i've select all items by Button click and do print using `DrawString` or `DrawImage` function which works fine but the problem if name of items are too long then i have clip width to 100px and text got wrap and print function call but on printing 2nd line, the items starting Y points unable to identify which creates problem. if i identifying 1st row height correctly then i can set 2nd rows Y coordinates accordingly that problem can be resolved but i dont know how to do. As you can see result in below image.

*The problem is in this piece of code:

```
        if (numbarcode < NBbarcode_perLine)
            startX += 150;
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(rectangleHeight.ToString());
            startX = 5;
            startY += 150; // space between 2 lines
            numbarcode = 0;
        }
```

[image]
code:

```
  // The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed. 
        private void PrintBarcodeEvent_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int startX = 5;
            int startY = 5;

            Database db = new Database();
            db.DBOpen();

            int NBbarcode_perLine = 5;
            int numbarcode = 0;

            int barcodePerPage = 35;
            int totalcodebar = listTobePrint.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < barcodePerPage; i++)
            {

                String code = listTobePrint[countbarcode].Code;
                String name = db.GetByValue(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 2);
                String price = db.GetByValueForInt(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code, 8);

                Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Phulkari by VIRSA", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                  startX, startY, new StringFormat());

                int x2 = startX + 3;
                int y2 = startY + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Util.ImageWpfToGDI(Util.GenerateBarcode(code)), x2, y2, 100, 50);

                int x3 = startX;
                int y3 = y2 + 50;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(code, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                    x3, y3, new StringFormat());

                int x4 = startX;
                int y4 = y3 + 15;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Rs." + price, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                    x4, y4, new StringFormat());

                // Measure string.
                SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
                stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(name, printFont);
                int width = (int)stringSize.Width;
                int height = (int)stringSize.Height;


                //MessageBox.Show(width.ToString() + ", Height: "+height);

                int x5 = startX;
                int y5 = y4 + 15;

                RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(x5, y5, 100, 0);
                int rectangleWidht = (int)rectangle.Width;
                int rectangleHeight = (int)rectangle.Height;

                //MessageBox.Show(rectangleHeight.ToString());

                e.Graphics.DrawString(name, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
                  rectangle, new StringFormat());

                numbarcode++;
                countbarcode++;


                if (numbarcode < NBbarcode_perLine)
                    startX += 150;
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(rectangleHeight.ToString());
                    startX = 5;
                    startY += 150; // space between 2 lines
                    numbarcode = 0;
                }


                if (countbarcode == totalcodebar) break;

                if (i == barcodePerPage - 1)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }

            }
            countbarcode = 0;
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            db.DBClose();
        }
```

Comment: hi zohaib!!  do you need to display all text or you accept to truncate it? do you know  the max length of the item?

Comment: i dont want to truncate i need to display all the text and remaining lines should adjust according to that text

Comment: @Frenchy as you can see first barcode text, its override to bottom barcode. i dont want this. i want to display all text and barcodes

Comment: how many barcodes have you in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one first solution is:
decrease one line of barcode and increase the space between two lines: (because you have the risk to have a cut line in bottom of page)

```
    int barcodePerPage = 30;//instead of 35
```

and you increase the space betwween two line

```
            if (numbarcode < NBbarcode_perLine)
                startX += 150;
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(rectangleHeight.ToString());
                startX = 5;
                startY += 200; // ***** space between 2 lines increased
                numbarcode = 0;
            }
```

this solution has the advantage to have the same number of barcode per page

another solution will be to calcul the number of char of next 35 barcode and following the number of char of item you choose the first way to print 35 barcode or if char is too long, the second way to print 30 barcode. if you dont know to do that i could help you
This solution could have different number of barcode per page

Another solution is to choose a little font for the item (arial 8 for example) and you could win space